# Reading 2 digit 7 segments with ESP32 using TM1650 maybe?

Tags: level-shifting, esp32, 7segmentdisplay, c++, automation

I have been trying to contact a [forum member](https://www.troublefreepool.com/threads/automation-of-intex-swg.228606/page-2#post-2128055) that has done a [modification to his pool equipment](https://www.troublefreepool.com/threads/automation-of-intex-swg.228606/) in order to control it remotely instead of having to go to the box every time and check on the codes. His has released the source code on his [github](https://github.com/tonyflores1006/intex-swg-iot) page.

However, I have a different model than he does so I do not think his ESP32 code will work on mine.

His equipment contains a TM1650 for the 2 digit 7 segment display. I am unable to find out if my version has the TM1650 or something else.

His schematic looks like this:
[image]

[image]

I have all the components that are displayed in the schematic. I have the ESP32 and the Level shifter.

[image]

Another forum member had the same chip but some pins were different. His schematic looks like this:
[image]

So, since I do not have the same setup as they do is there any IC I can get that would make reading the 2 digit 7 segments easier than trying to read each led and determining what letter/number is being displayed? I can use the 4n25/35 optocoupler to "press" any of the 6 buttons and have an analog read for the 8 LEDs to determine which ones of those are on. The only trouble I foresee is the 2 digit 7 segments reading.

**UPDATE 1**

So I'm looking at my version of the ESP32 that I have (Known as the Lolin32)

[image]

And looking at their schematic I see that they call out GPIO 16, 17, 18 & 19. However, I do not have the same pin layout as they do...Go figure...

[image]

- GPIO 19 -> SWG main board clock
- GPIO 18 -> SWG main board data
- GPIO 17 -> Display board clock
- GPIO 16 -> Display board data

[image]

So, I take it my layout would be:

> GPIO 19 -> GPIO 19 MISO
>
> GPIO 18 -> GPIO 18 CLK
>
> GPIO 17 -> GPIO 17 TX
>
> GPIO 16 -> GPIO 16 RX

That look correct?

Note: Also posted to the following forums:

> https://www.electronicspoint.com/forums/threads/reading-2-digit-7-segments-with-esp32.297108/
>
> https://forum.allaboutcircuits.com/threads/reading-2-digit-7-segments-with-esp32.186817/
>
> https://www.electro-tech-online.com/threads/reading-2-digit-7-segments-with-esp32.163357/
>
> https://www.eevblog.com/forum/projects/reading-2-digit-7-segments-with-esp32/new/#new
>
> https://www.electronics-lab.com/community/index.php?/topic/48746-reading-2-digit-7-segments-with-esp32/

Comment: don't ignore the electronics in the display panel ... what markings are on U1?

Comment: Only number i see on the 2 digit 7 segment display is **5261ASR**

Comment: Buy a cheapy usb logic analyser and see what happens on the two wires  used for communication. It could be I2C in which case the esp32 can easily talk this.

Comment: @StealthRT - Isn't this a simple shift register storing the state (code)? in this case what is the problem, I don't get it.